# Script to download video in batch with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I make a NodeJS script to download videos from a CSV list.
So far I can only download images in HTTP, but I could't figure out how to workaround for video and HTTPS. Your advice is appreciated. Below is my code to download Images.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var promiseCSV = require('./promiseCSV.js');
var request = require('request');
var path = "test.csv"

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

var i = 0;
promiseCSV(path).then(function (records) {
  next();
  function next(){
    download(records[i][0],'image/'+records[i][1], function(){
      i++;
      if (i < records.length) next();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors from trying to download a video? It looks good tho.

Comment: @MerunasGrincalaitis the file download is not executable with 0kb.

Comment: @MerunasGrincalaitis i tried it again and i am able to download already. However, how can i improve the code after the video is downloaded finish only it will go to the next video and download ? Thx

Comment: Are you storing your video names in the `records` matrix array? if so check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To dowload all the videos in your array do a `for` loop:

```
promiseCSV(path).then(function (records) {
  next();
  function next(){

  for(let b = 0; b < records[i].length; b++){
      download(records[i][b],'image/'+records[i][b+1], function(){
        i++;
        if (i < records.length) next();
      );
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i am now running my download of the list. Hopefully there will be no error. Now i am trying to revise the code to create directory if directory is not exist, so that it will be neat and organised.